# Combinatorial curvature of real projective plane

Tags: discrete-geometry, triangulations

There is a notion of combinatorial curvature due to Forman, see [here (published paper)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-002-0743-x) or [here (preprint).](http://math.rice.edu/~forman/ric.ps) I checked for a couple of small triangulations of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (6-vertex, 7-vertex, 9-vertex) and the 1-curvature seemed to be non-positive for any edge in these. Is there any triangulation which has at least some positive curvature? (My expectation is no: subdivisions seem to have more and more negative combinatorial curvature, so positive curvature triangulations should be small.) If there is no triangulation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with some positive curvature, what would be the explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any triangulation and any pair of adjacent faces $ABC$ and $BCD$. Now subdivide the shared edge $BC$ and both faces into three edges $BE$, $EF$, $FC$ and six faces $ABE$, $AEF$, $AFC$, $BED$, $EFD$, $FCD$. The edge $EF$ has $1$-curvature $2+2-2=2$.

Comment: Thanks. So does this mean that positive combinatorial curvature on $\mathbb{RP}^2$ detects possibilities to simplify the triangulation (by reverting the operation you described)?